# Big-O of an operation over a single linked list

Tags: linked-list, big-o, pseudocode

Suppose you've got a single linked list of size N, and you want to perform an operation on every element, beginning at the end.

I've come up with the following pseudocode:

```
while N > 0
    Current = LinkedList 
    for 0 to N
        Current = Current.tail
    end
    Operation(Current.head)
    N := N-1
end
```

Now I've got to determine which Big-O this algorithm is.
Supposing that Operation() is O(1), I think it's something like this:

```
N + (N-1) + (N-2) + ... + (N-(N-1)) + 1
```

But I'm not sure what Big-O that actually is. I think it is definitely smaller than O(N^2), but I don't think you can say its O(N) either ...

Comment: 1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2 which is O(n^2)

Comment: i dont quite understand your structure you have LinkedList called Current (it looks like a Node), that has tail and head? If you meant to be prev/next, then it's double linked; If they indeed are head/tail, the code above make no sense at all.

Comment: @bestsss: Well, you could say LinkedList is an object, and every time I enter the While-Loop, I reference it in Current. Calling "head" on Current (which is the LinkedList), returns the actual Element, and "tail" returns another LinkedList Object, containing, well, the tail...

Comment: okay :) well, you have weird ideas how to name "next"/"element". Head/tail are usually used outside the Node (itself) for designated Node(s) of the LinkedList. Either way you have nested loops, almost automatically means n2. If you need to process a single linked list backwards, inverse it 1st and then process it, inverse it again. Much faster than what you have now. Inverse is O(n), process is O(n) and inverse again is O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your equation is basically that of the [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and sums to *N(N+1)/2*.  I'll leave you to determine the `O()` from that!

A quicker way to do this is to construct a new list that is the reverse of the original list, and then perform the operations on that.

Comment: well, no need to construct new list [O(n) memory - for nodes/array]. inverse/process/inverse is viable as well.

Comment: @bestsss: How does one reverse a singly-linked list in-place, in *O(n)* time?

Comment: Using the very same Nodes, it's a classic problem; for example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686011/invert-linear-linked-list/4687305#4687305  -- no extra memory either, i.e. O(n) time, O(1) memory

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is *O(n^2)* as you suggest in your post.  You can do it in *O(n)*, though.

It's important to remember that Big-O notation is an *upper* bound on the algorithm's time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

[1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html) = 0.5*n^2+O(n)

This is O(n^2), and O(n^2) is tight, i.e. there is no lower runtime order that'd contain your runtime.

A faster algorithm that works from front-to-back could have O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: An algorithm that works from back to front can be *O(n)*, too. See @Oli's answer.

Comment: @Carl You're right, but that requires either O(n) additional memory, or temporary mutation of the liked list. Neither of which is nice.

Comment: that's absolutely true, but not nice and not possible are different things entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your runtime analysis is correct, the runtime is  1 + 2 + ... + N which is a [sum of the arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) and therefore = (N²-N) / 2.