# Complexity of this reverse singly linked list algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

What is the complexity of this algorithm? I am assuming it's O(N) but I'd like some clarification.
If I had a tail in the linked list, I would assume this would be even faster since I would completely avoid having that while(current != null) loop to loop to the end of the list.

```
public void reverse() {
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    if (this.head != null || this.head.next != null) {
        Node current = this.head;
        while (current != null) {
            stack.push(current);
            current = current.next;
        }
        Node last = null;
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            if (last==null) {
                this.head = stack.pop();
                last = this.head;
                continue;
            }
            last.next = stack.pop();
            last = last.next;
            if (stack.empty()) {
                last.next = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ask a clear question to tell us what you expect as an answer.

Comment: i reedited it, but essentially i am asking what the run time complexity of this algorithm would be

Comment: Yes it is O(n*constant) which is O(n), assuming that java Stack push and pop are O(1), which happens to be the case. Your space complexity is O(n) as well, and there are ways to do it in space complexity O(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing all the linked list elements onto stack by iterating the list this is one N then you iterate the stack which is another N so you Order notation in O(2N)

see [how to reverse a list with O(1) space and O(n) time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985365/how-to-reverse-a-list-with-o1-space-and-on-time)

Comment: so basically it's O(N) -- linear time?

Comment: You can drop the constant in front of the terms if I remember my complexity theory correctly, so yeha I would consider it O(N)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is in class O(N). You are using N times a static amount of operations (first loop) and then again a static amount of operations (second loop); Stack.pop() should be independent of "N"; So this means it's in class O(2N+c)... and O(2N+c) is in class O(2N) which is in O(N). In other words: the runtime of your routine increases linear with your number of elements in the stack.

OR simply: Yes, it is in class O(N).