# Traversing a LinkedList tail to head

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list, traversal

I need to traverse through this custom [linked list implementation](http://brianbolnick.com/sourcecode) and display its contents:

- from head to tail,
- then again from tail to head.

---

I was able to display the lists contents from head to tail pretty easily with a for loop:

```
        for (AccountRecordSerializable account : list) {
            System.out.println(account); 
        }
```

and everything works fine. Now I am trying to reverse that. In provided LinkedList class to use which has a LinkedListIterator class inside it as well. The iterator class has methods such as `hasNext()`, `hasPrevious()` which I know can be used to do so, but I'm not quite sure how to use that iterator through my LinkedList to do so.

Is there a simpler way as I had done before to reverse this? Or how would I use the Iterator class to iterate through my list so that it performs the task?

I apologize if this doesn't make any sense... let me know if you need clarifications..Thanks.

Comment: This is obviously a non-JDK class from your description; you need to post the code for at least the `Iterator` class from your implementation.

Comment: It is in the for+each loop so it implements Iterable<T> so its provide an Iterator that is JDK

Comment: Ok, there is quite a bit and I do not want to flood the page so I will set an external link

Comment: You want to save the reversed LinkedList? Check my answer, is it what you want?

Comment: @boris I added a link with the code.

Comment: Why have you added the code in that class ?

Comment: I think that is how my teacher wanted it..

Comment: but regardless of where it is thats the code provided

Comment: For sure that not the place for such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java LinkedList implements interface [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) that provides method [descendingIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this deque in reverse sequential order. The elements will be returned in order from last (tail) to first (head).

My advise for you is to implement that interfaces in your class, and the obtain reversed iterator.

The [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is data structure with some properties that you should use to get the implementation. The typical construction of linked list is that an element points to next one. In your case you have implementation that supports double linked list.

```
private int size = 0; // size can never be < 0
private DLNode<E> head;
private DLNode<E> tail;
```

In your code you have `DLNode` that stand for Double Linked Node.  This means that you can move from `head` to `tail` by using `hasNex()` and from tail to head using `hasPrevious()`.

In your class you have the class `LinkedListIterator`, that you can obtain with this method:

```
 public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index > size)) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index " + index+ " is out of range: 0 to " + size);
    }
    return new LinkedListIterator<E>(index);
}
```

So to print your elements you could do it like this.

```
 public <T> void printLinkedListFromHead(LinkedList<T> list) {

   for(ListIterator<T> iterator = list.listIterator(0); iterator.hasNext();) {
       System.out.println(iterator.next());
   }

 }
```

You should also create a separate class for your code, where you will put your code that contextually does not belong to the linked list implementation. The method  `readObjects`and  `writeObjects` do not belong to class. same as main.

---

If you would have standard Java LinkedList you could wrote something like this:

```
public <T> reversePrint(Deque deque) {

 for (Iterator<T> iterator = deque.descendingIterator(); iterator .hasNext();){
      System.out.println(iterator .next());
    }
}
```

To narrow the scope of iterator promote for loop than while.

Comment: Sorry, trying to make sense of the reversal part here. So in this instance, what would the deque to be passed through be? I am not very familiar with deque.

Comment: The `Deque` is an interface implemented in `LinkedList`. `Deque` allow to obtain the descendingIterator.

Answer (score 1):

A singly linked list is not meant to traverse from tail to head.There are couple of options you have

1. Reverse the linked list and traverse from head to tail (which will be tail to head for the original linked list)
2. Have a stack. Traverse the linked list and put the elements in the stack. Then keep popping the elements from the stack and print.

Comment: You are right but your answer is wrong. The source code linked to question shows that OP has Double Linked List.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided just to traverse backwards by assinging a cursor to the end of the list and iterating through with a `get(index)` which is then decremented. This is what I have:

```
        System.out.println("Tail to Head");
        for (int i = list.size - 1; list.get(i) != null; i--) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i));
                if (i == 0 ){
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I'm sure there are prettier ways to write it, but it fulfills its purpose for now.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.descendingIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator%28%29) will do what you want :)

Example:

```
LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
linkedList.add(1);
linkedList.add(2);
linkedList.add(3);


Iterator<Integer> iterator = linkedList.descendingIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

If you want to save a new LinkedList reversed.. just

```
LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
linkedList.add(1);
linkedList.add(2);
linkedList.add(3);


Iterator<Integer> iterator = linkedList.descendingIterator();
LinkedList<Integer> reversed = new LinkedList<Integer>();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    reversed.add(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: The only thing is that I have an iterator class created for me that I would probably need to use (seems redundant). I dont think I can just create an iterator object with it

Comment: I don't understand why someone just downvoted it since this answer says how to iterate it in the reverse order, but anyway: so you are using a your implementation of LinkedList?

Comment: The vote was rolled back. Why i do so ? The way you are using while loop instead of for. And the method how you copy to reverse the source list can be improved.

Comment: @Vash About the while or for i don't see any particular reason to prefer one over the other.. except the fact a for loop is more fast to write. About the copy -- maybe but i can't get any better way.. would be great if you include it in your answer.

Comment: That example show a valid implementation of some LinkedList. To gain the reverse functionality i would add the interface Deque and implements it.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno, The benefit from using for loop is that you narrow the scope of variable. In case of while you must declare it before loop and you will never use it after. In case of for loop, the iterator is not available outside the loop.

Comment: @Vash sounds good. What about the copy? My mind can't get anything better right now.. would be good to see a better way to do it.

Comment: You can use recursion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354875/reversing-a-linked-list-in-java-recursively or instead of has next implements something that check that has previous. The question is about data structure. A linked list is construction that an element has two pointers for next and for previous. If prev is null the is called head, if next is null then we reach the tail.

Comment: When i asked the question from the text i understand he wants to read the LinkedList in a reverse order and stop it. Nothing about a custom linked list or a copy of the list. That's why i answered with descendingIterator() and a sample example using while (Yup, ok the `for` example would be better but he could change it himself..). Anyway great answer you linked, i never liked recursion but how he implements it.. is great.

Comment: I have edited my answer to this question as it seams to be a home work im not posting final solution. As a train you may want to solve it for yourself (or open the JDK implementation to see how it was done there). The recursion is a beauty when properly used, buonanotte ;-).