# Possible to traverse the singly linked list from tail to head? (Java)

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to traverse singly LinkedList from tail to head with only using the for-loop.

For Example, I can traverse from head to tail with given head.

```
 LinkedList temp = head;    
   for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
      temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

But it is possible to do below code for traversing from tail to head?

```
 LinkedList temp = tail;    
   for (int i = 0; i < size -1; i++) {
      temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

Comment: It's called "singly-linked" because there's a single link between nodes. From one node to the next. If you want to be able to traverse backwards, you'd need a "doubly-linked" list.

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135464/traversing-a-linkedlist-tail-to-head) just have a look on this link

Comment: So, we can only traverse from head to tail which allows to traverse to only one direction?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest answer is, use `doubly linked` list if you need to traverse back to head.

However, if you really want to do so with a `singly linked list`, and if you don't want to use any library, you should implement the class on your own and add a reverse method like this:

```
public void reverse () {
    Node pointer = head;
    Node previous = null, current = null;
    while (pointer != null) {
        current = pointer;
        pointer = pointer.next;
        current.next = previous;
        previous = current;
        head = current;
    }
}
```

By this method you can reverse the current singly linked list, so you can traverse from the tail to head of original linked list.