# Best way to print a linked list(Singly and Doubly) in reverse?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Can someone provide the possible ways to print a Linkedlist in reverse in Java.
A way I understand would be to Recursively reach the end of list, And then start printing from the back and come to front recursively. 
Please share the possible ways.

I am using a Node having next and previous.

A Solution I figured is below. But here I need to create a variable each time entering in the recursive loop.  That's bad :(

```
public void reversePrinting(int count){
        if(count==0){       //to assign the root node to current only once
            current=root;
            count++;
        }
        else{               //moving current node to subsequent nodes
        current=current.nextNode;
        }
        int x= current.data;
        if(current.nextNode==null){
            System.out.println(x);
            return;
        }
        reversePrinting(count);
            System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you share your code and ask for specific help in fixing it...

Comment: difficult to help without seeing what code isn't working for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it is able reverse a linkedlist

```
public class DoReverse{ 
    private Node head; 
    private static class Node {
        private int value; 
        private Node next; 
        Node(int value) { 
            this.value = value; 
            } 
        } 
    public void addToTheLast(Node node) { 
        if (head == null) {
            head = node; 
        } 
        else { 
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null) 
                temp = temp.next; 
            temp.next = node; 
            } 
        } 
    public void printList(Node head) { 
        Node temp = head; 
        while (temp != null) { 
            System.out.format("%d ", temp.value); 
            temp = temp.next; 
            } 
        System.out.println(); 
        } 

    public static Node reverseList(Node head){

        Node prev = null;
        Node current = head;
        Node next = null;

        while(current != null){
            next = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        head = prev;
        return head;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        DoReverse list = new DoReverse(); 
        // Creating a linked list 
        Node head = new Node(5);
        list.addToTheLast(head); 
        list.addToTheLast(new Node(6)); 
        list.addToTheLast(new Node(7)); 
        list.addToTheLast(new Node(1)); 
        list.addToTheLast(new Node(2)); 
        list.addToTheLast(new Node(10));
        System.out.println("Before Reversing :");
        list.printList(head); 


        Node reverseHead= list.reverseList(head);
        System.out.println("After Reversing :");
        list.printList(reverseHead);


        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not copy the list so that it is reversed:

[Reversing a linked list in Java, recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354875/reversing-a-linked-list-in-java-recursively)

And then loop the copy of the list like your normally would?