# Recursively reverse a Linked List

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

This is a common question and has multiple references but none actually answers my specific question. While practicing online coding I came across the problem of reversing a linked list recursively. This is my normal code which works.

```
void Reverse(Node curr){

   if(curr.next == null){
       head = curr;
       return;
   } 
   Reverse(curr.next);
   Reverse(curr.next);
   Node p = curr.next;
   p.next = curr;
   curr.next = null; 
}
```

However the method signature that I need to complete is as follows,

```
Node Reverse(Node head){
}
```

Head is not a static value so I can't access it even if I write a helper function. Can someone help me modify my existing logic to align to this method signature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversing a linked list in Java, recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354875/reversing-a-linked-list-in-java-recursively)

Comment: I'm aware of that post and the similar solution that the post provides, but the logic is quite different. I want to stick to my current logic.

Comment: Since the return type is Node, What do you want to return to the method that calls Reverse ?

Comment: The head of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your head as global and then define it inside the main.

```
class Node{
    private Node list;

    void reverseMe(Node curr){
       //your method
    }

    Node reverse(Node list){
        reverseMe(list);
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        list = createHead();
        //the rest
        list = reverse(head);
    }
}
```