# reverse double linked list using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am writing program to reverse double linked list using recursion.
I know how to implement iteratively. but stuck in recursion.

Here is what I have

```
public static Node reverseRecurseDoubleLinkedList(Node node){
        if (node==null || node.next==null)
            return node;
        Node newNode = reverseRecurseDoubleLinkedList(node.next);
        node.next.next=node;
        node.next=null;
        node.prev=newNode;
        return newNode;
    }
```

I see the `prev` pointers are not set properly. but `next` pointers are in fact correct.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354875/reversing-a-linked-list-in-java-recursively?rq=1

Comment: @DuyAnhPham: no its not. i am asking for double linked list, read the question first.

Comment: There is no point to reverse a double headed link list...You could just swap head and tail references.

Comment: @Rugal: Simply swapping head and tail is not sufficient, since the `next` and `prev` members of each node would not be properly set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, one way to simplify thinking about recursive code is to only consider the guarantees that are offered when a recursive call is complete. You then need to check that these guarantees hold in the basic case that stops recursion (e.g. empty list, or list with a single node), and that they are maintained with each additional recursive call.

There are a few issues in the code provided:

- the condition that stopped recursion did not handle correctly the situations when `node.next == null`. The `node.prev` field should have been set to `null` in that case.
- the `newNode` variable name may cause some confusion. It represents the new head of the reversed list (which was the tail of the initial list). I renamed it to `newHead`.
- related to the point above, the assignment `node.prev=newNode;` is not correct -- we do not want the `prev` of each node to point to the head of the new list.

After incorporating these aspects, the code below correctly reverses the list:

```
public static Node reverseRecurseDoubleLinkedList(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return node;
    }

    if (node.next == null) {
        node.prev = null;
        return node;
    }

    Node newHead = reverseRecurseDoubleLinkedList(node.next);
    node.next.next = node;
    node.prev = node.next;
    node.next = null;

    return newHead;
}
```