# How can I recursively invert a linked list with a void method?

Tags: java, list, recursion, reverse

Im having trouble inverting a linked list with a void method. Im only alowed to use two pointer nodes (p,q). I´ve found several methods but not a void one. I need the root list to be modifed itself(that´s why it has to be a void method). The method has to be recursive(I know base definitions are different in void methods). Here's what i've done so far(not much).

public method:

```
public void reverse(){
        reverse(first, null);
    }
```

private method:

```
private void reverse(Node p, Node q){
    if(p.next!=null)
        reverse(p.next,p);
    p.next=q;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354875/reversing-a-linked-list-in-java-recursively

Comment: All you have to do is to update the head of the list once you reached the end, and it should be fine.

Comment: yes I did. Still I couldnt find a working recursive void method. They all return the modified list. I need it so that the list itself inverts.

Comment: Why does the private method have to be `void`? I understand that the public method is `void`, because it has to update the `first` field instead of returning anything, i.e update the state of the list, but why does that mean the private method has to be `void` too?

Comment: @Andreas Right. So are you saying that I can make the private method a Node method instead of a void one and therefore use the base definitions as in this post? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354875/reversing-a-linked-list-in-java-recursively?lq=1).

Comment: @edgarwl That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works great! You might just not be testing it correctly. Here's how I tested it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node last = new Node(4, null);
    Node first = new Node(1, new Node(2, new Node(3, last)));

    System.out.println("before: " + first);
    Node.reverse(first);
    System.out.println("after: " + last);
}

private static class Node {
    private int val;
    private Node next;
    public Node(int v, Node n) { val = v; next = n; }
    public String toString() { return val + (next == null ? "" : " -> " + next); }

    public static void reverse(Node first) {
        reverse(first, null);
    }
    private static void reverse(Node p, Node q) {
        if (p.next != null)
            reverse(p.next, p);
        p.next = q;
    }
}
```

Output

```
before: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
after: 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

---

**Edit**: To avoid the need for `last` in the calling code, add a method `getLast()` so that your `public reverse` can return it when the reverse is finished. Since Java is only pass-by-value, you can't change the caller's value of `first` from inside of the method `reverse`. Make these changes:

```
// in Node
private Node getLast() { return next == null ? this : next.getLast(); }
public static Node reverse(Node first) {
    Node last = first.getLast();
    reverse(first, null);
    return last;
}

// in main()
System.out.println("before: " + first);
first = Node.reverse(first); // update the value of first afterwards
System.out.println("after: " + first);
```

Comment: Great! I think im going the right way. But still I think I need to modify the `first` value at some point in my code. So that it can be written the exact same way you did but instead of printing `System.out.println("after: " + last);` I can print `System.out.println("after: " + first);` **after running the method** and after the list has been modified. Thank you :)

Comment: I think that what my method does is this:
Original: **1** -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
Modified: **1** <- 2 <- 3 <- 4
How can I modify the `last` node so that it actually becomes my `first` node.

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer with a solution for that. See what you think :)

Comment: Awesome. I think that works great for me! Thank you so much bro.